# EBICS Response HPB: Decrypt with PHP

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I'm trying do decrypt the banks response of a HBP-Request but until now without success.

According the specification it exists a transaction key, which is asymmetric encrypted.
Further the OrderData, which is compressed, encrypted and base64-coded.

I could decrypt the orderdate with the following code, but afterwards i get an error during compressing.

```
openssl_open(base64_decode($orderdata), $open, base64_decode($trxkey), $pkeyid) or die(openssl_error_string());
```

Does anyone could give me a hint?

Thanks

Comment: You should post your code, the parameters and an exact error message. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post the error message.